# SqlParameter not working with LIKE Operator ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I have this query to fetch a few rows from a table in SQL Server database. But the query always return 0 rows. There is no error but this query doesn't match any rows.

```
string name = //string data from http request


 var apriori = db.Aprioris.SqlQuery("Select top 5 * from Apriori where Antecedent LIKE '%@name%' ", new SqlParameter("@name", name)).ToList();
```

i've tried using `=` instead of `LIKE` then It worked but in this contest I should use the `LIKE` keyword because I need a partial match.

I also tried this one

```
string name = "\'"+"%"+prod.Name+"%"+"\'";//'%stringval%'
var apriori = db.Aprioris.SqlQuery("Select top 5 * from Apriori where Antecedent LIKE @name ", new SqlParameter("@name", name)).ToList();
```

But none of it worked, Anybody know why it doesn't work?

There is nothing wrong with my data in table because this one works perfectly

```
var apriori = db.Aprioris.SqlQuery("Select top 5 * from Apriori where Antecedent LIKE '%meatballs%' ").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the data type of **name** from `string to SqlDbType` and it worked. 
This is the modified code

```
            SqlParameter name = new SqlParameter();
            name.ParameterName = "@name";
            name.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
            name.Value = "%" + prod.Name + "%";// prod.Name from http request
            var apriori = db.Aprioris.SqlQuery("Select top 5 * from Apriori where Antecedent LIKE @name", name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably all you want to do is like this:

```
string name = //string data from http request


 var apriori = db.Aprioris.SqlQuery("Select top 5 * from Apriori where Antecedent LIKE @name ", new SqlParameter("@name", "%" + name + "%")).ToList();
```

Since you need to add the "%" in the value of the parameter, not in the query. And also the name of the parameter in the query string should not be surrounded by quotes.